# AddressDoctor WSDL and PHP

Tags: php, wsdl

I am trying to CALL WSDL FROM php
http://validator2.addressdoctor.com/addBatch/Batch.asmx?wsdl

```
define('ADDRESSDOCTOR_WSDL_URL','http://validator2.addressdoctor.com/addBatch/Batch.asmx?wsdl');
define('ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_LOGIN','myaccount');
define('ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_PASSWORD','password');

$useinfo = array(
"CustomerID"=>ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_LOGIN,
"DepartmentID"=>0,
"Password"=>ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_PASSWORD
);

$addressinfo = array(
"Street"=>"main st",
"Locality"=>"wayne",
"PostalCode"=>"07035",
"Province"=>"NJ",
"Country"=>"USA");

$addressinfo1 = array(
"Street"=>"100 newark tpk",
"Locality"=>"wayne",
"PostalCode"=>"07470",
"Province"=>"NJ",
"Country"=>"USA");

$array_of_add = array("Address"=>$addressinfo,"Address"=>$addressinfo1);

$client = new SoapClient(ADDRESSDOCTOR_WSDL_UR);
$function = $client->Validate(array("addBatchRequest"=>array("Authentication"=>$useinfo,"Parameters"=>$paramenters,**"AddressCount"=>2**,"Addresses"=>$array_of_add)));

$result = $function->ValidateResult;

print_r($result);
```

It give me error
 does not match number of supplied addresses.

If I write

```
$function = $client->Validate(array("addBatchRequest"=>array("Authentication"=>$useinfo,"Parameters"=>$paramenters,"AddressCount"=>1,"Addresses"=>$array_of_add)));
```

**"AddressCount"=>2** is changed to **"AddressCount"=>1**
 It works and outputs single result for "Address"=>$addressinfo1 even though i have passed two addresses Address"=>$addressinfo,"Address"=>$addressinfo1. I can pass upto 10 count in each batch request. But I am not able to get it. Can please some one help me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to put

```
$array_of_add = array($addressinfo,$addressinfo1);
```

instead of

```
$array_of_add = array("Address"=>$addressinfo,"Address"=>$addressinfo1);
```